# Regular expression Date separation

Tags: php, regex

I have the following date like this

20120809

I want to separate this with '-' and make this to

2012-08-09

using regex.

Is there is a simple solution to this using PHP? Anything will be fine.

Comment: Why do you *specifically* need to use a regular expression for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you must do this with a regex? You can get the answer with just regular maths.

Comment: @ruakh...because i believe regex is an easy way...the problem is i am a newbabie to regex

Comment: @andrew can use php too...How can i use regular math for thi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use `date_parse_from_format`, [the docs are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php). In your case, that would make for:

```
date_parse_from_format('Ymd',$dateIn);
```

Gives an array back, so you can pretty much do as you please from there on end

As @Rocket said, you can also get the `DateTime` object, which gives you all sorts of goodies, too. [more docs to read ;)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Or you can use `date_create_from_format` to get a `DateTime` object back instead of an array.

Comment: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20120911');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: Thanks Rocket..."date_create_from_format" really Awesome like you:-)GBU

Answer (score 3):

use `date()` and `strtotime()`?

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('20120809'));
```

Comment: Be weary of date settings, depending on the default time zone, this could be interpreted differently: Ymd or Ydm? it's not entirely clear...

Comment: +1 to Elias' note... my solution assumes consistant/structured inputs

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with others that you don't need a regex to do this, but...

```
preg_replace('/(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)/', '\1-\2-\3', $str);
```

With PHP though, you can use `substr_replace` to insert dashes:

```
$str = substr_replace($str, '-', 4, 0);
$str = substr_replace($str, '-', 7, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a regex, it's simple.  Just use `\d` with a quantifier like `{4}`.

```
preg_replace('/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/', '$1-$2-$3', '20120809');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex for this thing is completely wrong and there are better ways to do that like substr() ...

But here is what you want:

```
<?php

$string = '20120809';

preg_match( '/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/', $string, $parts);

unset($parts[0]);

$result = implode('-', $parts); //2012-08-09

?>
```